# Make image stay where it is

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website, with three images in a row. When the mouse hovers over a picture it increases in size. My problem is, that when I hover over the first picture, the second picture moves horizontally, and when I hover over the second picture, the third picture moves vertically. Hovering over the third picture works fine, but I guess that's besause it's aligned to the right.
Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#pic1").mouseover(function() {
  $("#pic1").animate({'width': '367px', 'height': '245px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic2").mouseover(function() {
  $("#pic2").animate({'width': '367px', 'height': '245px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic3").mouseover(function() {
  $("#pic3").animate({'width': '367px', 'height': '245px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic1").click(function() {
  $("#pic1").animate({'width': '50px', 'height': '30px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic2").click(function() {
  $("#pic2").animate({'width': '50px', 'height': '30px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic3").click(function() {
  $("#pic3").animate({'width': '50px', 'height': '30px'}, 1000);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="allShow" id="pic1" style="width: 50px; height:30px" align="left" alt="Flagge der UN" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg"/> 
<img class="allShow" id="pic2" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50px; height:30px" alt="Ban Ki-Moon" src="http://www.un.org/sites/www.un.org/files/styles/thumbnail-responsive/public/2014/11/25/secretary-general-ban-ki-moon-speaking-press-conference_01b0a.jpg?itok=yCtESIJq"/>
<img class="allShow" id="pic3" alt="Mitglieder" style="width: 50px; height:30px; margin-top: -30px" align="right" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54c7de19e4b0cece214f32ca/t/54db8f27e4b0512a94d8c06e/1423675177419/UN-flags.jpg?format=1500w" />
```

Comment: you should use transform:scale(8);  it will not disturb your layout (tune to your needs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a `<table>` for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#pic1").mouseover(function() {
  $("#pic1").animate({'width': '367px', 'height': '245px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic2").mouseover(function() {
  $("#pic2").animate({'width': '367px', 'height': '245px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic3").mouseover(function() {
  $("#pic3").animate({'width': '367px', 'height': '245px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic1").click(function() {
  $("#pic1").animate({'width': '50px', 'height': '30px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic2").click(function() {
  $("#pic2").animate({'width': '50px', 'height': '30px'}, 1000);
 });
 $("#pic3").click(function() {
  $("#pic3").animate({'width': '50px', 'height': '30px'}, 1000);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: table; width: 1200px">
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 400px; vertical-align: top">
      <img class="allShow" id="pic1" style="width: 50px; height:30px" align="left" alt="Flagge der UN" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg"/> 
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 400px; vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">
      <img class="allShow" id="pic2" style="width: 50px; height:30px" alt="Ban Ki-Moon" src="http://www.un.org/sites/www.un.org/files/styles/thumbnail-responsive/public/2014/11/25/secretary-general-ban-ki-moon-speaking-press-conference_01b0a.jpg?itok=yCtESIJq"/>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 400px; vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">
      <img class="allShow" id="pic3" alt="Mitglieder" style="width: 50px; height:30px;" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54c7de19e4b0cece214f32ca/t/54db8f27e4b0512a94d8c06e/1423675177419/UN-flags.jpg?format=1500w" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Markasoftware: I know, but for a start this might be enough to understand .. but here you are, divs :)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `transform:scale(x);`

```css
img:hover {
  transform: scale(8);
  ;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
img {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: 99999s;
  /* freeze hover effect */
}
img + img {
  transform-origin: top center;
}
img:last-of-type {
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<p>reload to reset or reset transtion on img</p>
<img class="allShow" id="pic1" style="width: 50px; height:30px" align="left" alt="Flagge der UN" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg" />

<img class="allShow" id="pic2" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50px; height:30px" alt="Ban Ki-Moon" src="http://www.un.org/sites/www.un.org/files/styles/thumbnail-responsive/public/2014/11/25/secretary-general-ban-ki-moon-speaking-press-conference_01b0a.jpg"
/>
<img class="allShow" id="pic3" alt="Mitglieder" style="width: 50px; height:30px; margin-top: -30px" align="right" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54c7de19e4b0cece214f32ca/t/54db8f27e4b0512a94d8c06e/1423675177419/UN-flags.jpg" />
```